# Directory and subdirectory user access without changing ownership or group

Tags: permissions

I have a directory with lots of subdirectories. For reasons, I can't change the owner or group of this directory or it's subdirectories.

I need to have a user that can access some of the subdirectories but not all. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Access Control Lists.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, ACLs will be your best bet:

```
[root@server ~]# setfacl -m d:u:usr1:rw tmpdir1
[root@server ~]# setfacl -m u:usr1:rw tmpdir1
[root@server ~]# getfacl tmpdir1/
# file: tmpdir1/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:usr1:r-x                <--
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:usr1:r-x        <--
default:group::r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::r-x
```

Setting the Default option on a folder means that the user will create future files in that directory with these permissions.